# Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS dual boot with Windows 7 on separate Hard Drives

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, lts

I'm trying to make dual boot (Ubuntu server and Windows 7), installed on separated hard drives. But GRUB don't recognize Windows 7 boot.
I've tried "sudo grub-update" along with "sudo os-prober". The "os-prober" finds the Windows 7, but when I update GRUB configuration, the Windows entry don't show up. I've tried so hard to find a solution, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran `grub-mkconfig` to allow grub to find Windows AND add it to the config file?

[grub-mkconfig](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Invoking-grub_002dmkconfig.html)